# Can we have the ability to undo up or downvotes on meta regardless of when you voted?

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, locked-votes

Can we make it so people can undo up or down votes regardless of time voted? I want this feature request *only* on the meta sites. Can we do this? If not, why?

This would be helpful because sometimes on meta there is a feature and you down vote it, later you might think it's good. Then you will want to up vote it, but you can't!

Also, users can't ‘suggest edits‘ on meta.

Comment: We *can*, but should we? Please edit your post to explain how you think this change would be beneficial.

Comment: @AdamLear edited

Comment: Why have you changed your mind/vote if the post hasn't changed?

Comment: @RobertLongson  because if there's a specific feature that you think is bad, but then you think is good, you can change it.

Comment: Why would that happen?

Comment: @RobertLongson Presumably because you vote before you actually understand what's being requested in the feature and, through comments perhaps it's clarified and you change your mind... or maybe some time passes and you realize that the issue being discussed actually is an issue... there are tons of explanations...

Comment: @Catija exactly

Comment: How many times are you wanting to change your your mind?  Just the original and one reversal?

Comment: FYI, the [tag:meta] tag is for questions specific to this site only, MSE. Also, it's not about the upvotes and downvotes themselves, but rather the process of locking them, which prevent undoing them.

Comment: In a way  this could **make** sense on meta. I can assume that changing you opinion on a post is something that can happen more easily here, where votes are meant to express agreement and not just "quality". Just imagine this scenario: you see a feature request that you initially deem unneeded, then some time later someone comes in and post an answer that makes you realize something you haven't considered before: at that time you may actually want to change your original vote on the proposal

Comment: That said, I am also pretty worried this would end up like Rathony describes in his answer: less attention given to votes, lots of changes every day and a general noise. So, while this could be useful in some edge chases, it should also have some sort of limitation. Maybe some (small) rep cost?

Comment: It's relevant for things like scope and policy discussions.  Something got discussed back in 2011 and, based on context then, people voted.  Time passed, the site changed, people's opinions changed.. and anybody who revisits that discussion finds his vote locked in.  Sometimes the right thing to do is to start a new meta discussion, but sometimes being able to reconsider a vote in light of experience would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

When you visit [Help Center > Privileges > Vote Up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [Vote Down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down), you can read

> You have a limited number of votes per day, use them wisely.

It is better not to vote when you are not sure about the usefulness of any Meta post so that you don't have to think about undoing your vote. If we know we can undo our vote whenever we want, we will more likely spend less time judging the quality of a post before casting a vote. As long as we are more careful when voting, we don't need to undo our vote. But if you really want to cancel or reverse your vote,

> You can leave a comment requesting the OP edit the post so that you
>   can reverse your vote.

or

> You can wait until an edit is made.

Should there be no edit, there is nothing we can do about it but move on. A lesson learned.

Comment: I still want a mod to confirm this if it's going to happen or not going to happen

Comment: @Alex Sure, you can wait for another answer or see the number of votes on this answer.

Comment: ***I can read***, it has 5 votes

Comment: @Alex I didn't mean you can't read it. If a user agrees with my answer, they simply upvote it. If they don't agree, they will downvote it or write another answer. That's how it works here.

Comment: look at my stack overflow profile and how long I've been in that site, I think that I know how stack exchange works